# Bundling TeX source files (and unbundling) for the purpose of editing

Tags: tex-core, unicode, utf8

I would like to bundle several LaTeX source files (into one) so it could be edited and unbundled (for further processing).

During the old times (of only ASCII TeX sources) this could be accomplished with `shar`, in particular `shar -m -w *.tex > Bundled.shar` would contain all the files in plain format (no encoding) and one could edited the larger bundled format and open it back after editing.

With non-ascii LaTeX source files, this is no longer an option. Either the files are uuencoded before being included (and so it can't be edited) or they are included as-is and the unbundling does not work as expected. See [this shar question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377780/problem-with-shar-on-ubuntu-on-text-files)

What do you use for editing multiple TeX source files at once?

Comment: I use an editor that can edit multiple files so I'd never see a need for this.  You could put all the files into `filecontents` environments at the start of the main document so  that latex itself unpacked them all at the start of the run.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, which editor do you use on several files at the same time?  Do you need to switch from file to file? Can you make this into an answer? It looks like an interesting solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I use an editor that can do edits over multiple files so would not see a need to bundle them in to one for editing. Here is the three file source of the above document in three emacs buffers.

[image]

However if you want it all as one file:

```
\begin{filecontents}{zzz1.tex}

\section{Вступление}

Привет, мир.
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{zzz2.tex}
\section{Something}

áéíóú
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

\input{zzz1.tex}

\input{zzz2.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarllsle I have not used Emacs before, would it work to edit hundreds of files at once? Or do they have to be displayed in order to be acted on? I am not sure if was completely clear, but I do want the files separated - so I could act on them with other tools, like for example ``sed -i ... ab*.tex`` so to some extent ``filecontents`` negate this possibility.

Comment: @TeXApprentice  at work I work on the manual for our library product which is xml rather than tex but a couple of thousand files and it's no problem to do regular expression replace over all of them when needed, you can arrange that each is cleared from the editor as it is edited or leave them all in memory if you have the memory, basically I can't think of any reason when I'd want them all in one file for editing, in fact rather the opposite most tools it's easier to split the file up with `\input` or `\include` for ease of editing.

Comment: suppose you want to change ``aaa`` by either ``bbb`` or ``ccc`` depending on the local context and there are 3 occurrences of the string on some 1000 files (021.tex, 527.tex and 978.tex). With the bundling I would search for ``aaa`` and click ``next`` and ``next`` I am done. With all the files open in memory -- how do you locate the one where the string occurs?

Comment: I'd do a tags query replace of aaa to bbb and it'll find all the occurrences of aaa in any of the files then I hit space for yes or n for no as required. Or if there are too many to manually say yes/no I'd program the choice of whether to replace by bbb or ccc with a bit of emacs lisp.  if the are too big to hold in memory I have a similar loop that again only asks once for the replacement but opens and closes each file in turn so one file is in memory at a time, i can still do consistent edits over thousands of files, just as you can with your `sed` command line example. @TeXApprentice

Comment: Sure, but suppose it is not possible to automate -- you need to look at the text to decide if it is going to be ``bbb``  or  ``ccc``. Can you go to the file where it occurs directly, like in the bundled case?

Comment: @TeXApprentice as I said that is the simple case, tags-query-replace so I can tell it to use some list of files `*tex` or any specific list then do a tags-query-replace of aaa to bbb and it will fetch each file into the editor and ask for a yes or no to replace any instance of aaa it finds in any of the files, you don't have to know in advance which files to open and the tag file that has the file list can be saved alongside your document and always used by default whenever working on a particular document.

Comment: or direcd mode, see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-text-across-multiple-files.html

Comment: Many thanks, I understand now, and this seems to be a definite advantage of Emacs over Vim.